# Angular Ng-Repeat Ordered List

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am having trouble with Angular, this is my first time using it after taking the lessons in CodeAcademy. My code is as follows:

HTML:

```
<body style="padding-top: 0px;" data-spy="scroll" ng-app="SummerMill">
<section id="intro" class="main style1 dark">
<!-- Header -->            
<header ng-controller="MainController" id="header">

        <!-- Logo -->
        <h1 id="logo">Summer Mill</h1>
        <a ng-mouseover="locations()"
                style="color:black;text-decoration:initial;"
                id="logoii"
                href="http://localhost/locations">Locations</a>

        <!-- Nav -->
        <nav id="nav">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li ng-repeat="headerLink in headerLinks">{{headerLink.text}}</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

</header>
```

App.js

```
var app = angular.module('SummerMill', []);
```

MainController.js

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.headerLinks = [ 
        { 
            text: 'Intro', 
            alternativeText: 'Arlington'
        },
        { 
            text: 'Wholesale', 
            alternativeText: 'New York'
        }
    ];
}]);
```

The header just gives me `{{headerLink.text}}`

Why? :'(

Edit: It turned out that I had an error in an earlier script injected before angular that was causing the problem. Simply rearranging the order of the `<script src=""></script>` tags solved it for me.

So instead of this:

```
<script src="javascript/init.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
```

I did this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/init.js"></script>
```

Comment: If it is not parsing it there is probably an error in your console, check that and post the error

Comment: @KevinF No relevant errors in the console.

Comment: Do you have your <script> injection for Angular?

Comment: you can create a sample app on plunkr then we can help troubleshoot. Currently we don't even know whether your Angular app has been bootstrapped.

Comment: Running your code on plunkr works fine. I think your scripts are being loaded incorrectly and the code isn't executing.  http://plnkr.co/edit/DLkMpnwE7Osrf1v6UiSI

Comment: Yes, `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>` in the header and the module and controller in the footer.

Comment: @KevinF well it turns out an error I thought was irrelevant **was** relevant, an error in an earlier script must have stopped angular from loading properly. I changed the order of the `<script src="">` and it works now, mostly :P

thank you :)

Comment: @SummerDeveloper, this might be useful to someone else, so consider answering your own question.

Comment: @SummerDeveloper you should also edit your question to include the details and context of the other error you thought was irrelevant.  Otherwise your question and answer read like Q: "My code has no errors but it doesn't work (and it should)." A: "My code actually had an error I didn't mention, and fixing that fixed everything else"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem was that I had an error in an earlier script that was loading in the header, with angular originally being injected after this errant script.

Once I put angular first, everything was fine.

:)